# What's the corresponding multielement operator version of "numpy.logical_or"?

Tags: python, numpy, operators

To sum elements up, we have binary operator `np.add`, and moreover `np.sum` dealing with multiple elements. Likewise, we have `np.multiply` and `np.product` to do the multiplication.

But for `np.logical_or`, what's the corresponding multielement operator? Assuming I have the following array:

```
In [29]: a
Out[29]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

I want to have a method like `np.logical_or(a, axis=0)`, so that I could get such an array `[ True,  True,  True]`. Now the only way I could come up with is:

```
In [31]: a.sum(0).astype(bool)
Out[31]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

But that's not a good way because it will fail on array like:

```
array([[-1, -1],
       [ 1,  1]])
```

Comment: `sum` and `prod` are implemented as calls to `add.reduce` and `multiply.reduce`, and all binary ufuncs have the `.reduce` method, so even if `any` and `all` were not explicitly defined, they would be easy to produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of [`np.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) (for `logical_and`) or [`np.any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) (for `logical_or`).

```
In [11]: a.any(axis=1)
Out[11]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```